# Mysql sum of same field but different condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(17,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=999999;
```

I want from a single query to return the SUM of all records, as well as the SUM of the first 100 records.

Right now I use two separate queries:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM data
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) FROM data WHERE id<=100
```

My idea is related to optimizations so an UNION doesn't solve this.
I was thinking something like an IF with two variables.

```
IF id<=100 THEN SUM1+=amount
IF id>0 THEN SUM2+=amount
```

But I have no idea how to translate the above into MYSQL language without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries sum the first hundred, then starting at the 100th row up to an arbitrarily large number that will get all your rows.

```
select sum(a.amount) from (select amount from data limit 100) a
select sum(a.amount) from (select amount from data limit 100,999999999) a
```

Your idea of of the two variables will not result in an optimization, as it will most likely take a slower path through the database engine. You could combine the two queries above into :

```
select (select sum(amount) from data limit 100) as acount, (select sum(amount) from data limit 100,999999999) as bcount from dual
```

But this is likely no faster, as the database will break it into two queries internally anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no way so that the database would NOT break it into two queries internally?

Comment: Not really, it's pretty fundamental to how the database engine works. Anything you came up with that's tricksy and procedural is going to drop out of the highly optimized query paths and most likely be slower than the two queries anyways.

Comment: That said you will save a bit by using the single query version. Although the database will still run two separate queries, you'll save the overhead of database connections and result passing by making just one request to the db.

Comment: I was thinking and hoping that the DB pointer goes through each row of the table and then based on the comparison conditions it either places the `amount` value in the SUM of first100 or in the SUM of remaining100, without having to analyze each row twice.

Comment: You can probably make it do that, but the DB engine will have to check the comparison condition on every row, which will be ultimately slower.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select sum(if(id <= 100, amount, 0)) as first_hundred,
       sum(if(id <= 100, 0, amount)) as rest
from data
```

This gives you what you want - for each row, if the id is less than or equal to 100, the amount is summed into first_hundred, otherwise it is summed into rest.

The total for the entire table is the sum of first_hundred and rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `SUM` statements:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`id` <= 100, `amount`, 0)) AS `hundred group`,
       SUM(IF(`id` >= 0, `amount`, 0)) AS `all`
```